# Passing argument to cellfun matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, delimiter, cell-array

Hello I have a cell array of char (separated by underscore) that I would like to convert to double.
I do it in a `for` loop, but since the dimensions are very big, it takes a lot of time.
I would like to use `cellfun`, but I don't know how to pass the delimiter.

Can you help me?

```
listofwords = {'02_04_04_52';'02_24_34_02'};
for i = 1 : size(listofwords,1)
    listofwords_double(i,:) = str2double(strsplit(listofwords{i},'_'))./1000;
end

listofwords_double2= cellfun(@strsplit , listofwords);
```

**Benchmark**

As requested by Divakar

```
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.3398%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.4068%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -47.1129%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.2882%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.2325%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.0161%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.9728%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.4267%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.2867%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -46.3031%
```

Comment: Wow, that goes so bad for my evil script! :-) However, thanks for helping us settle the matter, I - and I'm sure @Divakar too - really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: @CST-Link Time to edit your conclusions in your solution I believe :)

Comment: @Divakar Haha, it might be, but not yet. :-) Soon, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use anonymous function like this -

```
listofwords_double2= cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,'_') , listofwords,'uni',0)
```

Another approach with `regexp` and a one-liner -

```
cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) str2double(regexp(x,'_','Split'))./1000 , listofwords,'uni',0))
```

---

## Performance oriented solutions

**Approach #1**

```
N = 4; %// Edit this to 10 in your actual case
cat_cell = strcat(listofwords,'_');
one_str = [cat_cell{:}];
one_str(end)=[];
sep_cells = regexp(one_str,'_','Split');
out = reshape(str2double(sep_cells),N,[]).'./1000; %//'# desired output
```

**Approach #2**

Benchmarking the above solution suggests `strcat` could prove to be the bottleneck. To get rid of that you can use a `cumsum` based approach for that part. This is listed next -

```
N = 4; %// Edit this to 10 in your actual case

lens = cellfun(@numel,listofwords);
tlens = sum(lens);
idx = zeros(1,tlens); %// Edit this to "idx(1,tlens)=0;" for more performance
idx(cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1)=1;
idx2 = (1:tlens) + cumsum(idx);

one_str(1:max(idx2))='_';
one_str(idx2) = [listofwords{:}];

sep_cells = regexp(one_str,'_','Split');
out = reshape(str2double(sep_cells),N,[]).'./1000; %//'# desired output
```

**Approach #3**

Now, this one uses `sscanf` and appears to be really fast. Here's the code -

```
N = 4; %// Edit this to 10 in your actual case
lens = cellfun(@numel,listofwords);
tlens = sum(lens);
idx(1,tlens)=0;
idx(cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1)=1;
idx2 = (1:tlens) + cumsum(idx);

one_str(1:max(idx2)+1)='_';
one_str(idx2) = [listofwords{:}];
delim = repmat('%d_',1,N*numel(lens));
out = reshape(sscanf(one_str, delim),N,[])'./1000; %//'# desired output
```

---

## Benchmarking

As requested by @CST-Link, here's the benchmark comparing his "Kraken" `eval` against `approach #3`. The benchmarking code would look something like this -

```
clear all

listofwords = repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},100000,1);
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc(); %// Warm up tic/toc
end

tic
N = 9; %// Edit this to 10 in your actual case
lens = cellfun(@numel,listofwords);
tlens = sum(lens);
idx(1,tlens)=0;
idx(cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1)=1;
idx2 = (1:tlens) + cumsum(idx);

one_str(1:max(idx2)+1)='_';
one_str(idx2) = [listofwords{:}];
delim = repmat('%d_',1,N*numel(lens));
out = reshape(sscanf(one_str, delim),N,[])'./1000; %//'# desired output
time1 = toc;
clear out delim one_str idx2 idx tlens lens N

tic
n_numbers = 1+sum(listofwords{1}=='_');
n_words   = numel(listofwords);
listofwords_double = zeros(n_numbers, n_words);
for i = 1:numel(listofwords)
        temp = ['[', listofwords{i}, ']'];
        temp(temp=='_') = ';';
        listofwords_double(:,i) = eval(temp);
end;
listofwords_double = (listofwords_double / 1000).';
time2 = toc;
speedup = ((time1-time2)/time2)*100;
disp(['Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = ' num2str(speedup) '%'])
```

And here are the benchmark results when the code is run for a few number of times -

```
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = 0.30609%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = 0.012241%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -2.3146%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = 0.33678%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -1.8189%
>> benchmark1
Speedup with EVAL over NO-LOOP-SSCANF = -0.12254%
```

Looking at the results and observing some negative speedups (indicating `sscanf` to be better in those cases) among some positive speedups, my opinion would be to stick with `sscanf`.

Comment: @Divakar First of all, thanks for admitting (implicitly) that `cellfun` is expressive but not efficient - which was my initial point. So I'll run the test tomorrow; I'm also curious about the outcome. Until soon. :-)

Comment: @Divakar Hi. 1) I run your benchmark test on MATLAB R2012a (Win, 2Gb RAM, Intel i5 vPro) and my script presented an approx. 12% speed-up. Moreover, if I switch the order of execution - my script first, then yours - I get 17%. 2) The statement about `sscanf` being faster than `eval` is not accurate. You're comparing a *single* call of `sscanf` with 100000 calls of `eval` so you don't account for the 99999 overheads in function call. 3) My challenge was for a million strings, not one hundred thousands: your approach gives gives me "out of memory" errors, because `cumsum`.

Comment: @Divakar So, I'd like your permission to add these conclusions to the answer. May I? :-)

Comment: @CST-Link On 1) I skipped clearing out memory at the end of your code, as that was the end of the benchmark script. So, if you are switching the order of the codes, please clear out all the variables used, just like
I did after toc of no-loop sscanf method. Also, could you increase the number of cells (which was one million in your test case) to the max until it throws out-of-memory error?

On 2) Well I have gone with no-loop sscanf, otherwise my approach would be identical to your sscanf based approach and there won't be any approach #3 or benchmark.

Comment: @CST-Link On 3) I had out-of-memory error with one million strings, that's why I settled for 100 thousand. Now, I have 4GB RAM. You said you have 2GB RAM (which is sort of rare these days I would think), so maybe
you can go with 10 thousand cells? With how many cells/strings did you get the "out of memory" error at cumsum?
Yeah sure, please go ahead and add whatever conclusions or results you have in your solution, would be interesting to have a look!

Comment: @Divakar No, I cleared my variables before executing your script, so no worries about my script hogging the memory before your script.

Comment: @CST-Link Oh wait, if you add anything to your solution, upvotes on your solution won't get to your rep. So, yeah go ahead and add to my solution I guess, I still have 5 revision left to abuse :) Just to remind you again, stretch that datasize ( one million or 100 thousand to that maximum extent where it stays within the memory limits).

Comment: @Divakar Okay, tested your script and 225'000 strings is still okay, while 230'000 will give out of memory. I guess that is because you duplicate the cell array in a single string, then you allocate the format string for `sscanf`, then you get the data for the result.

Comment: @CST-Link You got it! That's exactly I am doing there, everything in one go.

Comment: @Divakar I will add those conclusions to my answer alright.

Comment: @gabboshow Would you be kind enough to run the `benchmark1.m` that was added in the **Benchmarking** section? It would be awesome if you could do so. So, what you can do is copy and paste that benchmarking code and save as `benchmark1.m`. 
Then, from the command window, run 4-5 dummmy runs of it (just to "warm-up" the codes) by typing "benchmark1" and then again run it for 10 times and report us those 10 outputs (similar to what I have at the end) here in the comments?

Comment: @Divakar I put the benchmarking on my question since it was too long for a comment.. tnx

Comment: @gabboshow If I could bother you one last time on this. Could you increase that `100000` in `listofwords = repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},100000,1);` to as big as possible until you run into out-of-memory issues with the codes, let's say that is `N`. Re-do the whole thing with `listofwords = repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},N,1);` and report back the speedups again alongwith that `N`? Also, would be super-nice thing from you, if you could add the RAM you have. I would really really appreciate all of that! :)

Comment: @Divakar For the benchmark I'd like the final transposition removed, please, it was not part of my code.

Comment: @CST-Link The final transposition is required to get the output as requested in the question. It won't be a fair benchmarking otherwise, would it? :)

Comment: Haha, you're right. :-) However, I think this is going in an interesting direction, even though the @gabboshow's tests score so bad for my script. :-) It would be great to "decouple" the two benchmarks: each script should start with a fresh MATLAB session, and run, say, 10 times before displaying the cumulated runtime. Like this there won't be any issues of memory fragmentation before executing one script or the other. And it would be a great topic for a bounty!

Comment: @CST-Link I know what would be the next demands for benchmarking - Starting OS in command-line and only MATLAB, so that no other processes disturb our kraken eval. Then run the benchmarks and make sure eval gets to +12%. If it doesn't, we contact the headquarters of the ORNL to make our benchmark codes run on TB RAM system and again make sure +12% is achieved. If it doesn't we contact Mathworks to speedup eval. Good luck with these adventures! :D

Comment: I just realized that I might have offended you personally when I posted my challenge and added the comments regarding the performances of our scripts - from the implied sarcasm of your last comment. I'm sorry if that happened, I did'n mean it. However, I'm truly interested in 2 things: 1) if `sscanf` is really better than `eval` when evaluating a string as a number, 2) if loops are worse than "fake" vectorization (i.e. `cellfun`, `arrayfun` and like). I will put a +500 bounty rewarded to you and no one else on a Q regarding: execution speed; expressiveness; memory stress. Would you agree?

Comment: Also, I will delete my answer from this post: is really useless in context, so is not helping anyone but me - because I have to know. :-)

Comment: @CST-Link haha no!! No offense taken, trust me! But yeah I guess we went a little too much with the benchmarking stuff here! :) All's good. On your points in the last two comments, I need to get back to you tomorrow probably!

Comment: @CST-Link I think you must reconsider undeleting your solution! I loved that, specially the `sscanf` part that prompted me to go with  my `no-loop sscanf` approach!! On 2) I think fake loops are worse than actual loops as has been discussed numerous times on SO itself. On 1) There are a few issues there which didn't seem like fair to me to benchmark `eval` against `sscanf`. To start off, `eval` [isn't compiled](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). And there are all sorts of things with `eval` that has prompted Mathworks guys to advise us to avoid it. ..

Comment: @CST-Link So I don't think the benchmarks are totally pointless, as  someone might be interested in it. I mean I would be interested in `eval` too if I had seen speedups of 20-50% consistently (to overcome the negative aspects it come with), but that wasn't the case.. so didn't make sense to puruse it any further. Again, DO consider undeleting your post bud!!

Comment: @Divakar Oh, is okay. We can consider my deleted answer transferred here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528999/matlab-performance-benchmarking I adopted a less provocative tone in the posting, also (see, I'm learning stuff on several levels, not only on MATLAB's :D). Please to contribute by either: 1) editing the post with your suggestions, 2) adding your benchmarking, or totaly new solutions. I would like to credit you in the post for the code of `single_sscanf_solution`, if you agree - I needed to ask first.

Comment: @CST-Link Sure go ahead with the attribution stuff! That's a humongous post BTW! :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be:

```
listofwords_double2 = cellfun(@(x) str2double(strsplit(x, '_'))./ 1000, listofwords);
```

Just a side note: my version of Matlab does not have `strsplit`, so I cannot test it.

Comment: You need to use `UniformOutput` with false I think.

Comment: how can I get a matrix of doubles?

Comment: @gabboshow use `cell2mat` wrapping `listofwords_double2`.

Comment: can I use cell2mat inside cellfun...all in 1 line? :)

Comment: @gabboshow Let me ask you - Do you always have 3 underscores and 4 numbers in each cell?

Comment: @Divakar yes (actually I have 9), but yes the number of underscore is constant

Comment: @Divakar yes I have 10 numbers

Comment: @gire Got a challenge for you. :-)