# MATLAB performance benchmarking

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

### The set-up:

This post is about testing the performances of solutions to the following problem:

> *A cell array of `S` strings formatted as numbers separated by underscores is given, e.g.:*
>
> `list_of_words = repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},10,1);`
>
> *Is guaranteed for all strings that:*
>
> 1. *they contain only decimal digits and underscores;*
> 2. *the number of underscores is the same;*
> 3. *there are no two consecutive underscores.*
>
> *Write MATLAB code that would convert the cell array of strings to a numeric matrix `S`×`M` of doubles **(values 1000 time smaller)**, where `S` is the number of strings and `M` is the number of numbers in a string.*

A very similar problem was posted on StackOverflow, with several solutions proposed. The original goal was improving speed performance.

### The code:

Two of the solutions, designed for speed, seem to have wildly varying performances from one MATLAB installation to another, or even from one run to another. Also, they have really different implementation styles.

**In the dark corner** you'll find a solution that goes *against* MATLAB's most sacred tenets: `eval` is evil, and loops should be avoided at all costs. However, the code tries to optimise the speed by avoiding repeated memory allocations, by using the fast ways of converting strings to numbers, and by doing in-place operations:

```
%'eval_and_loops_solution.m'
function array_of_numbers = eval_and_loops_solution(list_of_words)

        n_numbers = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_');
        n_words   = numel(list_of_words);

        array_of_numbers = zeros(n_numbers, n_words);

        for k = 1:n_words
                temp = ['[', list_of_words{k}, ']'];
                temp(temp=='_') = ';';
                array_of_numbers(:,k) = eval(temp);
        end;

         %'this is a waste of memory, but is kind of required'
        array_of_numbers = transpose(array_of_numbers / 1000);

end
```

*Note:* The original solution returned the result as `M`×`S` `double` array. The code was adapted for `S`×`M`; however, this adaptation consumes twice the memory. And yes, I wrote this solution.

**In the clear corner** you'll find a solution true to MATLAB spirit, that avoids using loops and `eval`, favoring a single `sscanf` read of *all* the strings (which is a clever way of avoiding the overhead of calling the function `S` times):

```
%'single_sscanf_solution.m'
function array_of_numbers = single_sscanf_solution(list_of_words)

        N = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_'); %'hard-coded in the original'
        lens = cellfun(@numel,list_of_words);
        tlens = sum(lens);
        idx(1,tlens)=0;
        idx(cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1)=1;
        idx2 = (1:tlens) + cumsum(idx);

        one_str(1:max(idx2)+1)='_';
        one_str(idx2) = [list_of_words{:}];
        delim = repmat('%d_',1,N*numel(lens));
        array_of_numbers = reshape(sscanf(one_str, delim),N,[])'./1000;

end
```

*Note:* This solution belongs to [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar).

**The referee** is made up of two functions: one that generates test cases, and one that does the timig.

The test case generator groups in a cell array underscore-delimited strings out of 10 random integers between 1 and 9999 (for the sake of simplicity); however, an implementation should only assume that the numbers are positive or zero, and the number should fit in a `double`:

```
%'referee_test_case.m'
function list_of_words = referee_test_case(n_words)

        NUM_PER_WORD  = 10;
        NUM_MAX       = 9999;

        word_format   = [repmat('%d_', 1, NUM_PER_WORD-1), '%d'];
        list_of_words = cell(n_words,1);

        fprintf('Generating %d-words test case...\n', n_words);
        for k = 1:n_words
                list_of_words{k} = sprintf(word_format, randi(NUM_MAX, [1, NUM_PER_WORD]));
        end;

end
```

The timing function takes as arguments a test case and an arbitrary number of processing function handles; it is implemented such as errors in one function should not bother the execution of the others. It uses `timeit` as recommended by @Divakar and @LuisMendo; for those who don't have this function in their default MATLAB installation, it may be downloaded from MATLAB Central / File Exchange:

```
%'referee_timing.m'
function referee_timing(test_case, varargin)
        %' Specify the test case as a cell array of strings, then the function '
        %' handles that will process the test case.                            '
        %'                                                                     '
        %' The function uses timeit() to evaluate the performance of different '
        %' processing handles; if your MATLAB installation does not have it    '
        %' natively, download the available version from File Exchange:        '
        %'                                                                     '
        %'     http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function '

        fprintf('Timing %d-words test case...\n', numel(test_case));
        for k = 1:numel(varargin)
                try
                        t = timeit(@() varargin{k}(test_case));
                        fprintf('  %s: %f[s]\n', func2str(varargin{k}), t);
                catch ME
                        fprintf('  %s: Error - %s\n', func2str(varargin{k}), ME.message);
                end;
        end;
end
```

### The problem:

As said before, the results seem to vary from one MATLAB installation to another, and even from one run to another. The problem that I propose is three-fold:

1. On your specific MATLAB installation (version + OS + HW), how well the two solutions perform compared to eachother?
2. Is it possible to improve one solution or the other in a sizable way?
3. Are there even faster MATLAB-native (e.g. no MEX or special toolboxes) solutions based on completely different ideas/functions?

For point 1. (benchmarking), please create in your MATLAB path the four function files `eval_and_loops_solution.m`, `single_sscanf_solution.m`, `referee_test_case.m`, `referee_timig.m` and other functions that you might want to test (for example, the implementations proposed by answers). Use them for several numbers of words, e.g. like this script:

```
%'test.m'
clc;
feature accel on;  %'tune for speed'

%'low memory stress'
referee_timing( ...
   referee_test_case(10^4), ...
   @eval_and_loops_solution, ...
   @single_sscanf_solution ... %'add here other functions'
);

%'medium memory stress'
referee_timing( ...
   referee_test_case(10^5), ...
   @eval_and_loops_solution, ...
   @single_sscanf_solution ... %'add here other functions'
);

%'high memory stress'
referee_timing( ...
   referee_test_case(10^6), ...
   @eval_and_loops_solution, ...
   @single_sscanf_solution ... %'add here other functions'
);
```

When posting the results, please specify your MATLAB version, the OS, the size of RAM and the CPU model. **Please be aware that these tests might take some time for large number of words!** However, running this script will not alter the content of your current workspace.

For points 2. or 3. you can post code that use the same in/out conventions as `eval_and_loops_solution.m` and `single_sscanf_solution.m`, along with the benchmarking that supports the claim.

### The bounties:

I will up-vote every benchmarking answer, and I encourage everybody to do that. Is the least that one can do for people that contribute with their skills, time and processing power.

A +500 bounty bonus will go to the author of the fastest code, be it one of the two proposed, or a third new one that outperforms them. I really hope that this will match the general agreement. The bonus will be given in a <del>month</del> week from the original date of posting.

Comment: Haha You don't give up, do you!? :)

Comment: @Divakar Haha, no. :-) I'm still curious. And I hope that the tone of the posting is more appropriate now.

Comment: The tone is very appropriate, and funny!

Comment: Is the number of characters the same for all cells (i.e. with left zero padding)?

Comment: @LuisMendo I suspect it was so in the original problem. However, for the purpose of this post, we shouldn't assume fixed number of digits in a number. However, the zero padding can happen, of course.

Comment: Also, are you sure tic/toc inside functions is a good idea? Maybe use `timeit` instead?

Comment: I agree with @Divakar. `timeit` should be the referee, as it's more reliable than `tic`/`toc`

Comment: +1, I like this. If you're paid to optimize such a script you're a cunning **** =P

Comment: @RobertP. Haha, no, I'm not paid, it's curiosity. And also a bit o pride. :-)

Comment: I will change the code. BTW, are you worrying about `tic`/`toc` because the overhead of accessing `global`s from inside a function? I think that this is the order of milliseconds the worst, while the execution times are the order of tens of seconds.

Comment: @Divakar <del>However, yes, I will change the code.</del> Apparently I don't have this function on my MATLAB version (R2012a). I'm not sure how to use it. Could you add it to an alternative code?

Comment: @CST-Link Sure, let me look into it.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the edit. Is it possible that the function is this one? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function/content/timeit.m

Comment: @CST-Link That might be it! Give it a try!

Comment: This cell array isn't perhaps being read in from a file is it? If the data originates in a file and is in the same form, you may have other options.

Comment: @horchler It is possible (in the original post) that the data was read from a file, actually is highly probable. However, this posting is looking for the performance of the code assuming the cell array is already available.

Comment: @CST-Link: I ask this because the most efficient way to do this may be to read the data in as doubles directly using `textscan`. The underscores can be treated as delimiters. If you wanted to post a sample file, I'd be happy to try to demonstrate a solution and compare it to others. Also, you might indicate what order of magnitude `S` and `M` normally are in your application.

Comment: @horchler Oh, I understand, and thanks for the input. However, the "practical" problem wasn't posted by me; you may find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487246/passing-argument-to-cellfun-matlab You could suggest an alternate take on it by directly processing the file - though the answer was already chosen.

Comment: Looking for fastest on `list_of_words = repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},10,1);`? or some other input? Of course, we mustn't repmat our solutions too. But I mean what must be the datasize? Also, are we assuming upto three digit numbers?

Comment: @Divakar I see the point... I will think of a more interesting way of generating the dataset. The idea was that the numbers are arbitrary - no other assumptions than the ones specified. Of course, the numbers should have integer values and fit in a `double`, but this goes without saying.  Also, I will change my `solution_referee()` to use the `timeit` function, with a link to the Matlab Central file for those who don't have the file from the default MATLAB installation. I would rather work in a function than in a script: I don't like Base workspace. :-)

Comment: @CST-Link Not sure if you would like it, but here goes one suggestion - http://pastebin.com/SNgQy0LW

Comment: Are we entertaining `gpuArray` based codes, as posted in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555344/3293881)?

Comment: @Divakar Then you are not comparing numbers from the same hardware...  Not to worry, your latest with sprintf seems fastest.  I'll post benchmarks on two different machines in an hour or two.

Comment: @chappjc Agreed on that, at least it could be a fun thing, just like `mex` ones :) And a motivation on why and how vectorization could be beneficial.

Comment: I've added new benchmarks on two different machines in [my second post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26560439/2778484).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

This first approach in a broad sense has two parts. The first one gets us one big long string that has all the characters from the cell array with underscores separating
two cells, which is essentially implemented with `cumsum`. The second one based on `bsxfun` gets us the desired numeric output in the desired format.

The code would look something like this -

```
function out = solution_cumsum_bsxfun(list_of_words)

N = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_'); %// Number of "words" per cell
lens = cellfun('length',list_of_words); %// No. of chars [lengths] in each cell
tlens = sum(lens); %// Total number of characters [total of lengths]
cumlens = cumsum(lens); %// Cumulative lengths

%// Create an array of ones and zeros. 
%// The length of this array would be equal to sum of characters in all cells. 
%// The ones would be at the positions where new cells start, zeros otherwise
startpos_newcell(1,tlens)=0;
startpos_newcell(cumlens(1:end-1)+1)=1;

%// Calculate new positions for all characters in the cell array with 
%// places/positions left between two cells for putting underscores
newpos = (1:tlens) + cumsum(startpos_newcell);

%// Create one long string that has all the characters from the cell arary
%// with underscores separating cells
one_str(newpos) = [list_of_words{:}];
one_str(cumlens + [1:numel(cumlens)]') = '_'; %//'#

pos_us = find(one_str=='_'); %// positions of underscores
wordend_idx = pos_us - [1:numel(pos_us)]; %// word end indices
wordlens = [wordend_idx(1) diff(wordend_idx)]; %// word lengths
max_wordlens = max(wordlens); %// maximum word length

%// Create mask where digit characters are to be placed
mask = bsxfun(@ge,[1:max_wordlens]',[max_wordlens+1-wordlens]); %//'#

%// Create a numeric array with columns for each word and each row holding a digit.
%// The most significant digits to least significant going from top to bottom
num1(max_wordlens,size(mask,2)) = 0;
num1(mask) = one_str(one_str~='_') - 48;

%// Finally get the desired output converting each column to a single
%// number, reshaping to desired size and scaling down by a factor of 1000
out = reshape(10.^(max_wordlens-4:-1:-3)*num1,N,[]).'; %//'#

return;
```

**Approach #2**

This a slight variation of approach #1 in that it does the job of first part with `sprintf`. Now, the idea came to me after seeing it in action in 
[@chappjc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538681/3293881). I appreciate him on letting me use it in this modified version.

Here's the code -

```
function out = solution_sprintf_bsxfun(list_of_words)

N = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_'); %// Number of "words" per cell

%// Create one long string that has all the characters from the cell arary
%// with underscores separating cells
one_str = sprintf('%s_',list_of_words{:});

pos_us = find(one_str=='_'); %// positions of underscores
wordend_idx = pos_us - [1:numel(pos_us)]; %// word end indices
wordlens = [wordend_idx(1) diff(wordend_idx)]; %// word lengths
max_wordlens = max(wordlens); %// maximum word length

%// Create mask where digit characters are to be placed
mask = bsxfun(@ge,[1:max_wordlens]',[max_wordlens+1-wordlens]); %//'#

%// Create a numeric array with columns for each word and each row holding a digit.
%// The most significant digits to least significant going from top to bottom
num1(max_wordlens,size(mask,2)) = 0;
num1(mask) = one_str(one_str~='_') - 48;

%// Finally get the desired output converting each column to a single
%// number, reshaping to desired size and scaling down by a factor of 1000
out = reshape(10.^(max_wordlens-4:-1:-3)*num1,N,[]).'; %//'#

return;
```

**Approach #3**

This is an altogether new approach based on `getByteStreamFromArray` -

```
function out = solution_bytstrm_bsxfun(list_of_words)

allchars = [list_of_words{:}];
digits_array = getByteStreamFromArray(allchars);

%// At my 32-bit system getByteStreamFromArray gets the significant digits 
%// from index 65 onwards. Thus, we need to crop/index it accordingly
digits_array = digits_array(65:65+numel(allchars)-1) - 48;
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
N = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_'); %// Number of "words" per cell
lens = cellfun('length',list_of_words); %// No. of chars [lengths] in each cell
cumlens = cumsum(lens)'; %//'# Cumulative lengths
% ----------------------------------------------------------
pos_us = find(digits_array==47);
starts = [[1 cumlens(1:end-1)+1];reshape(pos_us+1,N-1,[])];
ends = [reshape(pos_us-1,N-1,[]) ; cumlens];
gaps = ends(:) - starts(:) + 1;

maxg = max(gaps);
mask1 = bsxfun(@lt,maxg-gaps',[1:maxg]');

num_array(maxg,numel(lens)*N)=0;
num_array(mask1) = digits_array(digits_array~=47);
out = reshape(10.^(maxg-4:-1:-3)*num_array,N,[]).';

return;
```

---

GPU versions of the above approaches are listed next.

**Approach #4**

```
function out = soln_sprintf_bsxfun_gpu(list_of_words)

N = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_'); %// Number of "words" per cell

%// Create one long string that has all the characters from the cell arary
%// with underscores separating cells. Now this one uses sprintf as
%// firstly proposed in @chappjc's solution and he has agreed to let me use
%// it, so appreciating his help on this.
digits_array = gpuArray(single(sprintf('%s_',list_of_words{:})));
digits_array = digits_array - 48;

mask_us = digits_array==47; %// mask of underscores
pos_us = find(mask_us);

wordend_idx = pos_us - gpuArray.colon(1,numel(pos_us)); %// word end indices
wordlens = [wordend_idx(1) diff(wordend_idx)]; %// word lengths
max_wordlens = max(wordlens); %// maximum word length

%// Create a numeric array with columns for each word and each row holding a digit.
%// The most significant digits to least significant going from top to bottom
num1 =  single(zeros(max_wordlens,numel(pos_us),'gpuArray')); %//'
num1(bsxfun(@ge,gpuArray.colon(1,max_wordlens)',...
    max_wordlens+1-single(wordlens))) = digits_array(~mask_us); %//'

%// Finally get the desired output converting each column to a single
%// number, reshaping to desired size and scaling down by a factor of 1000
outg = reshape(10.^(max_wordlens-4:-1:-3)*num1,N,[]).'; %//'#
out = gather(outg);
```

return;

**Approach #5**

```
function out = soln_bytstrm_bsxfun_gpu(list_of_words)

us_ascii_num = 95;
allchars = [list_of_words{:}];

%// At my 32-bit system getByteStreamFromArray gets the significant digits 
%// from index 65 onwards. Thus, we need to crop/index it accordingly
alldigits = getByteStreamFromArray(allchars);
digits_array1 = gpuArray(alldigits(65:65+numel(allchars)-1));
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
lens = cellfun('length',list_of_words); %// No. of chars [lengths] in each cell
N = sum(digits_array1(1:lens(1))==us_ascii_num)+1; %// Number of "words" per cell
lens = gpuArray(lens);
cumlens = cumsum(lens)'; %//'# Cumulative lengths
% ----------------------------------------------------------
mask_us = digits_array1==us_ascii_num; %// mask of underscores
pos_us = find(mask_us);
starts = [[1 cumlens(1:end-1)+1];reshape(pos_us+1,N-1,[])];
ends = [reshape(pos_us-1,N-1,[]) ; cumlens];
gaps = ends(:) - starts(:) + 1;

maxg = max(gaps);
mask1 = bsxfun(@lt,maxg-gaps',[1:maxg]');

num_array = zeros(maxg,numel(lens)*N,'gpuArray'); %//'
num_array(mask1) = digits_array1(~mask_us)-48;
out = reshape(10.^(maxg-4:-1:-3)*num_array,N,[]).'; %//'
out = gather(out);

return;
```

Comment: The difference is even greater on my machine: eval = 1.478, sscanf = 0.3423

Comment: @chappjc I believe it's because of the memory hungry `bsxfun` as I am stretching it too far on my low RAM system. Nevertheless, thank you on performing the tests!!

Comment: @Divakar I added to the posting code for generating test cases, a timing function that uses `timeit`, and a standard test script. I'm hoping that they're alright; once I have your acceptance, I hope you don't mind me removing the old `timeit`-based script that you proposed.

Comment: @CST-Link Sure go ahead with removing it. So, `referee_timing.m` is  the one that replaces it, right?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @Divakar I added the original division by 1000, since we agreed to stick with the exact format of original scripts, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @CST-Link `10.^(maxg-4:-1:-3)` internally takes care of that `division by 1000`. Would be nice if you consult before editing codes :)

Comment: Oh, damn, sorry then. My bad. :-)

Comment: Nice to see some undocumented action.  +1 and sorry for not doing it already!

Comment: @chappjc I gotta ask you for permission if I could use `sprintf` for replacing the creation of `one_str` in my `approach1.m`, as essentially that's what `one_str` is trying to achieve. After that line, the code would remain the same (based on bsxfun). Earlier I was hesitant to use it, but seems like Amro has used it too in his bunch of implementations, so thought maybe me too :) Let me know if I have the permission and you have every right to decline though :)

Comment: True, it's an important part of my proposed solution.  The use of a comma-separated list input and the `'%s_'` format specifier to get a 1D string was a non-obvious solution. Blah, blah.  Just kidding!  It's also a shamelessly effortless trick that looks lucky compared to your well-thought solutions.  Go ahead and use it, just acknowledge like you already did.  But re: Amro, I think he was more going for a meta-study.  His mods to everyone's solutions appear to be mostly just tweaks in the interest of letting each answer put a good foot forward.

Comment: I feel like I have to say that I don't claim that the use of `sprintf` was my idea, it was certainly posted first by chappjc. Like I said at the top of my post, I borrowed ideas from other solutions, with slight variations, for the purpose of comparing all implementations in one post. (I also removed the division by 1000 because I felt it was not essential to the benchmarks; in case of Divakar's code I adjusted the exponents in 10.^(..) to compute whole numbers not fractions).

Comment: @chappjc Updated the codes here (changes being few optimizations and that `sprintf` trick being included) and and have uploaded benchmark results with the benchmark codes in the [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555344/3293881). Could you look into those benchmark codes and see if you could run those at your end?

Comment: @Amro Requested chappjc and now requesting you :) So, as I said in the earlier comment and now repeating - I have updated the codes here and and have uploaded benchmark results with the benchmark codes + source codes in the [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555344/3293881). Would love to see results at some other end! :)

Comment: @Divakar: done. see my latest edit. The MEX solutions are still faster :)

Comment: @CST-Link Thank you on offering the bounty!! Well, there was no clear winner it seems, so must had been hard for you to decide on the bounty. But, this question has gathered has some quality answers with unique approaches. People looking to work with cell arrays can surely look into these for performance and the lovely benchmarking techniques started by Amro would be pretty useful too. So overall all these must be good resources for future readers! :)

Comment: @CST-Link On the original discussion about comparing eval and sscanf, well .. based on the various results presented here, couldn't see a clear winner either. Guess, we can call it a tie, that would be a fair thought.

Comment: Congrats!  You earned it!

Comment: @chappjc With some help on the `sprintf` from you! :) So thank you!! Just not sure how fair it was on others with very close runtime results on their solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a bunch of implementations for you to benchmark (all pure MATLAB). Some of them borrow ideas from the other solutions.

```matlab
function M = func_eval_strjoin(C)
    M = eval(['[' strjoin(strrep(C,'_',' ').',';') ']']);
end

function M = func_eval_sprintf(C)
    C = strrep(C,'_',' ');
    M = eval(['[' sprintf('%s;',C{:}) ']']);
end

function M = func_eval_cellfun(C)
    M = cell2mat(cellfun(@eval, strcat('[',strrep(C,'_',' '),']'), 'Uniform',false));
end

function M = func_eval_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        M(i,:) = eval(['[' strrep(C{i},'_',' ') ']']);
    end
end
```

```matlab
function M = func_str2num_strjoin(C)
    M = reshape(str2num(strjoin(strrep(C.','_',' '))), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2num_sprintf(C)
    C = strrep(C,'_',' ');
    M = reshape(str2num(sprintf('%s ',C{:})), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2num_cellfun(C)
    M = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num, strrep(C, '_', ' '), 'Uniform',false));
end

function M = func_str2num_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        M(i,:) = str2num(strrep(C{i}, '_', ' '));
    end
end
```

```matlab
function M = func_sscanf_strjoin(C)
    M = reshape(sscanf(strjoin(C', '_'), '%f_'), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_sscanf_sprintf(C)
    M = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s_',C{:}),'%f_'), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_sscanf_cellfun(C)
    M = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) sscanf(c, '%f_'), C, 'Uniform',false).').';
end

function M = func_sscanf_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        M(i,:) = sscanf(C{i}, '%f_');
    end
end
```

```matlab
function M = func_textscan_strjoin(C)
    M = textscan(strjoin(C', '_'), '%.0f', 'Delimiter','_');
    M = reshape(M{1}, [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_textscan_sprintf(C)
    M = textscan(sprintf('%s_',C{:}),'%.0f', 'Delimiter','_');
    M = reshape(M{1}, [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_textscan_cellfun(C)
    M = cell2mat(cellfun(@(str) textscan(str, '%.0f', 'Delimiter','_'), C).').';
end

function M = func_textscan_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        x = textscan(C{i}, '%.0f', 'Delimiter','_');
        M(i,:) = x{1};
    end
end
```

```matlab
function M = func_str2double_strsplit_strjoin(C)
    M = reshape(str2double(strsplit(strjoin(C','_'),'_')), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_strsplit_sprintf(C)
    M = strsplit(sprintf('%s_',C{:}), '_');
    M = reshape(str2double(M(1:end-1)), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_strsplit(C)
    M = cellfun(@(c) strsplit(c,'_'), C, 'Uniform',false);
    M = str2double(cat(1,M{:}));
end

function M = func_str2double_strsplit_cellfun(C)
    M = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) str2double(strsplit(c,'_')), C, 'Uniform',false));
end

function M = func_str2double_strsplit_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        M(i,:) = str2double(strsplit(C{i},'_'));
    end
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_split_strjoin(C)
    M = reshape(str2double(regexp(strjoin(C.','_'), '_', 'split')), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_split_sprintf(C)
    M = regexp(sprintf('%s_',C{:}), '_', 'split');
    M = reshape(str2double(M(1:end-1)), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_split(C)
    M = regexp(C, '_', 'split');
    M = reshape(str2double([M{:}]), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_split_cellfun(C)
    M = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2double, regexp(C, '_', 'split'), 'Uniform',false));
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_split_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        M(i,:) = str2double(regexp(C{i}, '_', 'split'));
    end
end
```

```matlab
function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens_strjoin_1(C)
    M = reshape(cellfun(@str2double, regexp(strjoin(C.','_'), '(\d+)', 'tokens')), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens_strjoin_2(C)
    M = regexp(strjoin(C.','_'), '(\d+)', 'tokens');
    M = reshape(str2double([M{:}]), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens_sprintf_1(C)
    M = reshape(cellfun(@str2double, regexp(sprintf('%s_',C{:}), '(\d+)', 'tokens')), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens_sprintf_2(C)
    M = regexp(sprintf('%s_',C{:}), '(\d+)', 'tokens');
    M = reshape(str2double([M{:}]), [], numel(C)).';
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens(C)
    M = regexp(C, '(\d+)', 'tokens');
    M = cat(1,M{:});
    M = reshape(str2double([M{:}]), size(M));
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens_cellfun(C)
    M = regexp(C, '(\d+)', 'tokens');
    M = cellfun(@str2double, cat(1,M{:}));
end

function M = func_str2double_regex_tokens_loop(C)
    M = zeros(numel(C),nnz(C{1}=='_')+1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
        x = regexp(C{i}, '(\d+)', 'tokens');
        M(i,:) = str2double([x{:}]);
    end
end
```

Most methods are variations of the same idea, only with slightly different implementations (e.g: using explicit for-loop vs. `cellfun`, using `strjoin` vs. `sprintf` to join a cell array of strings into one string, etc..).

Let me break it down a bit more:

- there's the `eval`-based solutions. We either apply `eval` in a loop, or we make a single call after flattening the strings into one.
- similarly there are solutions based on calling `str2num` (after replacing underscores with spaces). It's worth noting that `str2num` itself calls `eval` internally.
- there's also the `sscanf` and `textscan` solutions. Like before, we either use them in a loop, or called on one long string.
- another set of solutions are based on calling `str2double` after splitting the strings by the underscore delimiter. Again there alternative ways to split the strings (using `regex` with the "split" option, or using the `strsplit` function).
- finally there a set of solutions based on regular expression matching.

---

## EDIT:

I created a set of functions for benchmarking the various implementations ([GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/df8a6c3e79062639763f)). Here are the [pre-packaged files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/424831b1ad10ut0/bench_cell_string_parsing.zip?dl=0) with all solutions posted so far. I included the compiled MEX-functions (for 64-bit Windows), along with MinGW-w64 DLL dependencies.

Here are the results of running on my machine (Laptop with quad-core Intel Core i7 CPU, 8GB, Win8.1, MATLAB R2014a). I tested the following sizes: 10x10, 100x10, 1000x10, and 10000x10. As you can see, the MEX solutions do better as you increase the data size...

---

## EDIT#2:

As requested, I updated my test results with the latest solutions; I've added the modified versions of the MEX-file by @chappjc, and the GPU versions by @Divakar. Here is the [updated archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5oifevdtgtaov1/bench_cell_string_parsing_2.zip?dl=0) of files.

I'm using the same machine as before. I've increased the cell-array size up to 1e5. My GPU device is decent for a laptop:

```
>> gpuDevice
ans = 
  CUDADevice with properties:

                      Name: 'GeForce GT 630M'
                     Index: 1
         ComputeCapability: '2.1'
            SupportsDouble: 1
             DriverVersion: 5.5000
            ToolkitVersion: 5.5000
        MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
          MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
        MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
               MaxGridSize: [65535 65535 65535]
                 SIMDWidth: 32
               TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
                FreeMemory: 2.0453e+09
       MultiprocessorCount: 2
              ClockRateKHz: 950000
               ComputeMode: 'Default'
      GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
    KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
          CanMapHostMemory: 1
           DeviceSupported: 1
            DeviceSelected: 1
```

---

Here are the latest results:

[image: fig1]
[image: fig2]

```
>> t
t = 
                      func                      nrows    ncols       time   
    ________________________________________    _____    _____    __________
    'func_eval_cellfun'                            10    10       0.00044645
    'func_eval_loop'                               10    10        0.0001554
    'func_eval_sprintf'                            10    10       7.6547e-05
    'func_eval_strjoin'                            10    10       0.00056739
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                          10    10       0.00037247
    'func_sscanf_loop'                             10    10       0.00017182
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                          10    10       8.4928e-05
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                          10    10       0.00056388
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                         10    10       0.00039231
    'func_str2num_loop'                            10    10       0.00033852
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                         10    10       0.00010862
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                         10    10       0.00057953
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                        10    10       0.00044585
    'func_textscan_loop'                           10    10       0.00024666
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                        10    10       9.4507e-05
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                        10    10       0.00056123
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'           10    10       0.00018166
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_gpu_Divakar'       10    10        0.0029487
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'               10    10       0.00016396
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'              10    10       0.00012932
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_gpu_Divakar'          10    10         0.002315
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'                  10    10       0.00017191
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                       10    10       6.5514e-05
    'solution_mex_Amro'                            10    10       6.4487e-05
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                         10    10       4.2507e-05
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                        10    10       0.00027411
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'                     10    10       0.00013017
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                      10    10       0.00020458
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'               10    10       0.00011144
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'            10    10       0.00010528
    'func_eval_cellfun'                           100    10        0.0011801
    'func_eval_loop'                              100    10         0.001059
    'func_eval_sprintf'                           100    10       0.00025547
    'func_eval_strjoin'                           100    10        0.0011824
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                         100    10        0.0023356
    'func_sscanf_loop'                            100    10        0.0012338
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                         100    10       0.00031012
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                         100    10        0.0011334
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                        100    10         0.002635
    'func_str2num_loop'                           100    10        0.0028056
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                        100    10       0.00027899
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                        100    10        0.0012117
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                       100    10        0.0029546
    'func_textscan_loop'                          100    10        0.0018652
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                       100    10       0.00028506
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                       100    10         0.001125
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'          100    10       0.00040027
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_gpu_Divakar'      100    10        0.0032536
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'              100    10       0.00041019
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'             100    10       0.00031089
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_gpu_Divakar'         100    10        0.0026271
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'                 100    10        0.0012294
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                      100    10       0.00033501
    'solution_mex_Amro'                           100    10       0.00027069
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                        100    10       0.00010682
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                       100    10       0.00039385
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'                    100    10       0.00015232
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                     100    10        0.0010108
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'              100    10       0.00050153
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'           100    10       0.00026958
    'func_eval_cellfun'                          1000    10        0.0092491
    'func_eval_loop'                             1000    10         0.016145
    'func_eval_sprintf'                          1000    10         0.067573
    'func_eval_strjoin'                          1000    10         0.070024
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                        1000    10         0.020954
    'func_sscanf_loop'                           1000    10         0.011224
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                        1000    10        0.0022546
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                        1000    10        0.0058568
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                       1000    10         0.024699
    'func_str2num_loop'                          1000    10          0.02645
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                       1000    10          0.05713
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                       1000    10         0.060093
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                      1000    10          0.02592
    'func_textscan_loop'                         1000    10         0.017589
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                      1000    10        0.0020249
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                      1000    10        0.0055364
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'         1000    10        0.0018817
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_gpu_Divakar'     1000    10        0.0066003
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'             1000    10         0.001982
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'            1000    10        0.0015578
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_gpu_Divakar'        1000    10        0.0046952
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'                1000    10         0.011481
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                     1000    10        0.0027254
    'solution_mex_Amro'                          1000    10        0.0022698
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                       1000    10        0.0006967
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                      1000    10        0.0015025
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'                   1000    10       0.00041463
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                    1000    10        0.0093785
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'             1000    10        0.0038031
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'          1000    10        0.0020323
    'func_eval_cellfun'                         10000    10         0.083676
    'func_eval_loop'                            10000    10         0.098798
    'func_eval_sprintf'                         10000    10          0.60429
    'func_eval_strjoin'                         10000    10          0.63656
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                       10000    10          0.20675
    'func_sscanf_loop'                          10000    10           0.1088
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                       10000    10         0.021725
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                       10000    10         0.052341
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                      10000    10          0.24192
    'func_str2num_loop'                         10000    10          0.26538
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                      10000    10          0.53451
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                      10000    10          0.56759
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                     10000    10          0.25474
    'func_textscan_loop'                        10000    10          0.17402
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                     10000    10         0.018799
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                     10000    10          0.04965
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'        10000    10         0.019165
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_gpu_Divakar'    10000    10         0.031283
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'            10000    10         0.027986
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'           10000    10         0.017761
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_gpu_Divakar'       10000    10         0.024821
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'               10000    10          0.10885
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                    10000    10         0.025136
    'solution_mex_Amro'                         10000    10         0.021374
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                      10000    10        0.0060774
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                     10000    10        0.0076461
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'                  10000    10         0.002058
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                   10000    10          0.10503
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'            10000    10         0.035483
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'         10000    10         0.018772
    'func_eval_cellfun'                         1e+05    10          0.85115
    'func_eval_loop'                            1e+05    10          0.97977
    'func_eval_sprintf'                         1e+05    10           6.2422
    'func_eval_strjoin'                         1e+05    10           6.5012
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                       1e+05    10           2.0761
    'func_sscanf_loop'                          1e+05    10           1.0865
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                       1e+05    10          0.22618
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                       1e+05    10          0.53146
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                      1e+05    10           2.4041
    'func_str2num_loop'                         1e+05    10           2.6431
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                      1e+05    10              5.4
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                      1e+05    10           5.6967
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                     1e+05    10           2.5696
    'func_textscan_loop'                        1e+05    10           1.7175
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                     1e+05    10          0.19759
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                     1e+05    10          0.50314
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'        1e+05    10          0.21884
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_gpu_Divakar'    1e+05    10          0.23607
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'            1e+05    10          0.29511
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'           1e+05    10          0.19882
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_gpu_Divakar'       1e+05    10          0.17923
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'               1e+05    10           1.0943
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                    1e+05    10           0.2534
    'solution_mex_Amro'                         1e+05    10          0.21575
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                      1e+05    10         0.060666
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                     1e+05    10         0.072168
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'                  1e+05    10         0.024385
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                   1e+05    10           1.0992
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'            1e+05    10          0.36688
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'         1e+05    10          0.19755
```

Comment: Haha I see, you don't seem to be interested in benchmarking... :-) Alright: 1) `regexp` is slow, 2) `str2num` is actually `eval` in a wrapper, 3) `sscanf` and `textscan` are actually fast imo, but there's the overhead of calling them multiple times; in exchange must build large format strings for large input strings. 4) `str2double` might be interesting, I didn't try it. Hope this is not a DOS attack on the posting. :-)

Comment: @CST-Link `str2double` might be the worst option.  It was my first attempt and it is really slow.

Comment: @CST-Link: I don't claim those are all fast (in fact `regexp` and `str2double` are slow as a dog!). `sscanf` and `textscan` are indeed the fastest, followed by `eval`-based ones (up to a certain size). My point was just to show various approaches, which is what it seems you're looking for... If you want performance, go the C/C++ road :)

Comment: @Amro Thanks for having a look at the spectrum of solutions, and for doing a some tuning on the `sprintf`/`textscan` approach in particular. Once again it seems that temporaries are easily optimized by MATLAB. :) I didn't find an advantage of using `Delimiter` but tried it both ways (obviously, it was in the my comments), but did you find it helped on your machine?  If it looks the same way when I run your test bench (very nice, BTW) on my machines, I'll tweak my official solution similarly.

Comment: @chappjc: Same here, I didn't see much difference between setting `delimiter` or not.

Comment: Benchmark ZIP after unpacking gives "Undefined function 'func_eval_cellfun' for input arguments of type 'cell'."  :(

Comment: Ahh, needed to add the subdir to the MATLAB path.  Now can't find `strjoin`.  What version of MATLAB did you use?  I have 2012a.

Comment: yeah, I'm using R2014a. `strjoin` (and maybe some other functions) were added in recent versions. You're gonna need to modify a few things... Start by removing those `*strjoin*` tests

Comment: No matter, I just deleted all the ones with `strjoin` or `gpu` in the name.  But now it's missing `timeit`.  I really was hoping this was a self-contained download, but clearly it isn't meant to be.

Comment: @BenVoigt: it is. `timeit` was also added in recent MATLAB version. For older release you could use this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function. I think you're still gonna be missing the last part with the plotting because it's using `table` (which is also new functionality). So comment those too, sorry :( Let me see if I can prepare a version just for you ;)

Comment: @BenVoigt: ok, can you try this version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbjkcv34wsbndvi/bench_cell_string_parsing_2_alt.zip?dl=0 . Should work with all MATLAB releases. If you're not on Windows, you need to compile the MEX functions first for your platform, or simply remove any function with `mex` in its name..

Comment: @Amro Thank you for taking the time to do the benchmarks again! Just a quick question - Are you using `gputimeit` for timing GPU codes? My GPU based codes had `'_gpu'` at the end and I was using that string part to detect for GPU functions and thus use `gputimeit` in my latest benchmark codes.

Comment: @Divakar: yes I am. I had already updated the benchmark code accordingly: https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/df8a6c3e79062639763f#file-bench_runner-m-L28 (see the revisions history)

Comment: @Amro Okay that looks good! That bump for small datasizes for GPU codes got me worried there. I need to investigate on that I guess.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about small datasets (it's probably the overhead of transferring data between CPU and GPU memory). The results do vary slightly between different runs, I'm sure that spike would go away in a different repetition.. In my opinion, the top 15 or 16 functions are all comparable and the difference is not that important for sizable data!

Comment: Agreed on that last sentence. I would be really interested in seeing someone really pushing it into larger datasizes and seeing which of those top ones keep up! I think we will wait for results from @chappjc :)

Comment: @Amro: I've finished my own solution.  Not the very fastest, but I validated my concept.  Would be nice to see how it fares on your machine, because the CST only-loops version that's the best pure-MATLAB version on mine is middle of the pack on yours.

Comment: @BenVoigt: actually yours is pretty fast.. You guys shouldn't take my results as reference; the timings vary widely between MATLAB versions and machine specs!

Answer (score 6):

This builds on Amro's MEX solution.  Since the problem as defined by CST-Link is so tightly constrained, a fast implementation can be made by sacrificing robustness and forgoing error handling.  Hence, format the input as specified!

Substitute the main loop in Amro's source with the following for ~4x speed up, without multi-threading ([full source](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/5dbe74e5c26aa184bffa)):

```
// extract numbers from strings
for (mwIndex idx=0, i=0; idx<n_words; ++idx) {
    std::string str = getString(cellstr, idx);

    std::string::const_iterator istr = str.cbegin();
    for (; istr != str.cend(); ++istr) {
        if (*istr < '0' || *istr > '9')
        {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
            out[i] *= 10;
            out[i] += *istr - '0';
    }
    ++i;
}
```

More manual optimization can be done, but I'm going to bed.  Also, I'm planning to the multi-threaded version at some point, but it's pretty straightforward to add the pragma.

---

**Benchmarks (UPDATED T-minus 12 hrs until end of grace period)**

Benchmarks with Amro's latest package of functions plus Ben Voigt's solution show different timings on different machines, but for what it's worth it looks like there is a virtual tie between a few solutions. On my i7 laptop with R2014a 64-bit on Windows 8 (on CUDA), my textscan, Divakar's latest and Ben Voigt's solutions and are best, with indistinguishable performance differences. CST-Link's "all loops" is very close but consistently a hair slower than the others.  These benchmarks use up to 1e6 strings. **The size of the cell array decides the fastest method.**

Taking out the MEX solutions (and GPU because my of my laptop), the solutions are placed as follows for various numbers of rows.  Again, the results suggest that the appropriate method depends on the number of rows:

### i7 16GB R2014a

```
              Solution                  1e6     5e5     1e5     1e4     1e3     100
____________________________________    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____

'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'      1       2       2       5       5       4  
'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'        2       1       3       2       1       8  
'func_voigt_loop'                        3       3       5       1       2       1  
'func_textscan_sprintf'                  4       4       4       4       6       3  
'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'     5       5       6       3       3      10  
'solution_loops_CSTLink'                 6       7       7       7       8       6  
'func_sscanf_sprintf'                    7       6       1       6       7       7  
'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'         8       8       8       8       4       9  
'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'         9       9       9       9       9      11  
'func_textscan_strjoin'                 10      10      15      10      10      16  
'func_sscanf_strjoin'                   11      11      10      11      11      19  
'func_eval_cellfun'                     12      12      13      12      12      18  
'func_eval_loop'                        13      13      11      13      13      12  
'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'           14      15      14      14      14      13  
'func_sscanf_loop'                      15      14      12      15      15      15  
'func_textscan_loop'                    16      18      19      18      18      21  
'func_sscanf_cellfun'                   17      17      16      17      17      22  
'func_str2num_cellfun'                  18      19      18      19      19      23  
'func_str2num_loop'                     19      20      20      20      20      24  
'solution_sscanf_Divakar'               20      16      17      16      16      20  
'func_textscan_cellfun'                 21      21      21      21      21      25  
'func_str2num_sprintf'                  22      23      23      22      22       5  
'func_str2num_strjoin'                  23      24      25      23      23      17  
'func_eval_sprintf'                     24      22      24      24      24       2  
'func_eval_strjoin'                     25      25      22      25      25      14
```

[image]

[image]

```
>> t
t = 
                    func                    nrows    ncols       time   
    ____________________________________    _____    _____    __________

    'func_eval_cellfun'                       100    10       0.00074097
    'func_eval_loop'                          100    10        0.0006137
    'func_eval_sprintf'                       100    10       0.00017814
    'func_eval_strjoin'                       100    10       0.00068062
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                     100    10        0.0012905
    'func_sscanf_loop'                        100    10       0.00069992
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                     100    10       0.00022678
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                     100    10       0.00075428
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                    100    10        0.0014366
    'func_str2num_loop'                       100    10        0.0014904
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                    100    10       0.00020667
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                    100    10       0.00073786
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                   100    10        0.0018517
    'func_textscan_loop'                      100    10        0.0012629
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                   100    10       0.00020092
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                   100    10       0.00071305
    'func_voigt_loop'                         100    10       0.00017711
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'      100    10       0.00029257
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'          100    10       0.00028395
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'         100    10       0.00023879
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'             100    10       0.00066461
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                  100    10       0.00021923
    'solution_mex_Amro'                       100    10       0.00020502
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                    100    10       6.3164e-05
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                   100    10       0.00018224
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'                100    10       8.2565e-05
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                 100    10       0.00084008
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'          100    10       0.00033844
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'       100    10       0.00020396
    'func_eval_cellfun'                      1000    10        0.0058036
    'func_eval_loop'                         1000    10        0.0060269
    'func_eval_sprintf'                      1000    10         0.055797
    'func_eval_strjoin'                      1000    10         0.057631
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                    1000    10         0.011712
    'func_sscanf_loop'                       1000    10        0.0067405
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                    1000    10        0.0019112
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                    1000    10        0.0040608
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                   1000    10         0.013712
    'func_str2num_loop'                      1000    10         0.014961
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                   1000    10          0.04916
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                   1000    10         0.051823
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                  1000    10         0.017256
    'func_textscan_loop'                     1000    10         0.012454
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                  1000    10        0.0016489
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                  1000    10        0.0038387
    'func_voigt_loop'                        1000    10        0.0012892
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'     1000    10        0.0013951
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'         1000    10        0.0015138
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'        1000    10        0.0011496
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'            1000    10        0.0061538
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                 1000    10        0.0020528
    'solution_mex_Amro'                      1000    10        0.0019629
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                   1000    10       0.00051825
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                  1000    10       0.00085117
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'               1000    10       0.00025825
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'                1000    10        0.0078551
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'         1000    10        0.0031104
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'      1000    10        0.0016144
    'func_eval_cellfun'                     10000    10          0.05772
    'func_eval_loop'                        10000    10         0.061705
    'func_eval_sprintf'                     10000    10          0.54464
    'func_eval_strjoin'                     10000    10          0.57007
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                   10000    10           0.1192
    'func_sscanf_loop'                      10000    10         0.068017
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                   10000    10         0.019622
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                   10000    10         0.038232
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                  10000    10          0.13811
    'func_str2num_loop'                     10000    10          0.14812
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                  10000    10          0.48726
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                  10000    10          0.50528
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                 10000    10          0.17378
    'func_textscan_loop'                    10000    10           0.1241
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                 10000    10         0.016595
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                 10000    10         0.035599
    'func_voigt_loop'                       10000    10         0.012136
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'    10000    10         0.015908
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'        10000    10          0.02301
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'       10000    10         0.014862
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'           10000    10         0.063188
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                10000    10         0.020153
    'solution_mex_Amro'                     10000    10         0.019252
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                  10000    10        0.0051221
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                 10000    10        0.0066551
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'              10000    10        0.0014584
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'               10000    10         0.096345
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'        10000    10         0.031047
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'     10000    10         0.016736
    'func_eval_cellfun'                     1e+05    10          0.78876
    'func_eval_loop'                        1e+05    10           0.6119
    'func_eval_sprintf'                     1e+05    10           6.7603
    'func_eval_strjoin'                     1e+05    10           5.7204
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                   1e+05    10           1.2096
    'func_sscanf_loop'                      1e+05    10          0.68303
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                   1e+05    10          0.21101
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                   1e+05    10          0.55226
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                  1e+05    10            1.411
    'func_str2num_loop'                     1e+05    10           1.8229
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                  1e+05    10           6.1474
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                  1e+05    10            7.551
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                 1e+05    10           2.5898
    'func_textscan_loop'                    1e+05    10           1.7934
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                 1e+05    10          0.25421
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                 1e+05    10           1.1762
    'func_voigt_loop'                       1e+05    10          0.25602
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'    1e+05    10            0.265
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'        1e+05    10          0.35656
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'       1e+05    10          0.23481
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'           1e+05    10          0.86425
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                1e+05    10          0.28436
    'solution_mex_Amro'                     1e+05    10          0.27104
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                  1e+05    10         0.078901
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                 1e+05    10         0.096553
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'              1e+05    10          0.03679
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'               1e+05    10           1.3818
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'        1e+05    10          0.43994
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'     1e+05    10          0.21271
    'func_eval_cellfun'                     5e+05    10           3.7658
    'func_eval_loop'                        5e+05    10           3.8106
    'func_eval_sprintf'                     5e+05    10           32.383
    'func_eval_strjoin'                     5e+05    10           40.451
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                   5e+05    10           8.5704
    'func_sscanf_loop'                      5e+05    10            4.707
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                   5e+05    10           1.4362
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                   5e+05    10           2.8301
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                  5e+05    10           9.6439
    'func_str2num_loop'                     5e+05    10           10.453
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                  5e+05    10           35.818
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                  5e+05    10           37.277
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                 5e+05    10           12.418
    'func_textscan_loop'                    5e+05    10           8.8237
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                 5e+05    10           1.2793
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                 5e+05    10           2.6496
    'func_voigt_loop'                       5e+05    10           1.2486
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'    5e+05    10            1.324
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'        5e+05    10           1.8229
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'       5e+05    10           1.2113
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'           5e+05    10           6.5759
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                5e+05    10           1.4583
    'solution_mex_Amro'                     5e+05    10           1.3718
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                  5e+05    10          0.39711
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                 5e+05    10          0.48046
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'              5e+05    10          0.48174
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'               5e+05    10           7.7943
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'        5e+05    10           2.2332
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'     5e+05    10           1.2399
    'func_eval_cellfun'                     1e+06    10           7.3884
    'func_eval_loop'                        1e+06    10           7.5519
    'func_eval_sprintf'                     1e+06    10           69.868
    'func_eval_strjoin'                     1e+06    10           71.964
    'func_sscanf_cellfun'                   1e+06    10           15.061
    'func_sscanf_loop'                      1e+06    10           8.4163
    'func_sscanf_sprintf'                   1e+06    10           2.7099
    'func_sscanf_strjoin'                   1e+06    10           5.1453
    'func_str2num_cellfun'                  1e+06    10            17.42
    'func_str2num_loop'                     1e+06    10           18.165
    'func_str2num_sprintf'                  1e+06    10           60.902
    'func_str2num_strjoin'                  1e+06    10           63.579
    'func_textscan_cellfun'                 1e+06    10           20.423
    'func_textscan_loop'                    1e+06    10           14.309
    'func_textscan_sprintf'                 1e+06    10           2.2853
    'func_textscan_strjoin'                 1e+06    10           4.5216
    'func_voigt_loop'                       1e+06    10           2.2443
    'solution_bsxfun_bytestream_Divakar'    1e+06    10           2.3495
    'solution_bsxfun_cumsum_Divakar'        1e+06    10           3.3843
    'solution_bsxfun_sprintf_Divakar'       1e+06    10           2.0311
    'solution_eval_loops_CSTLink'           1e+06    10           7.7524
    'solution_loops_CSTLink'                1e+06    10           2.4947
    'solution_mex_Amro'                     1e+06    10            2.486
    'solution_mex_chappjc'                  1e+06    10          0.76551
    'solution_mex_omp_Amro'                 1e+06    10          0.92226
    'solution_mex_omp_chappjc'              1e+06    10          0.88736
    'solution_sscanf_Divakar'               1e+06    10           19.673
    'solution_sscanf_char_LuisMendo'        1e+06    10           3.8578
    'solution_textscan_sprintf_chappjc'     1e+06    10           2.0074
```

Next...

### X5550 24GB R2014b

The order is different, but the differences are again insignificant.

[image]

[image]

Timings exceed 30000 character limit, but I can post them somewhere if desired.  The order is clear though.

I suggest CST-Link disregard all these measurements in deciding.

---

Of course, the MEX solutions rule. The solution above with `std::string::const_iterator istr` is fast, even faster with OpenMP.  GCC 4.9.1 (pthreads) and VS2013 have comparable performance for this code.  [Threaded source here](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/bee3224045c4f92a4698).

Comment: have you tried different C++ compilers? for some reason VS2013 was consistently at least twice as slow as GCC (I'm using the latest MinGW-w64 GCC 4.9.1 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/seh/)). The threaded version was even worse..

Comment: @Amro The istringstream one or this?  But, no I haven't compared with GCC, although I do have MinGW-w64 installed (same as yours except the win32threads version) from an ffmpeg build I was doing.  I can try later.  By the way, I didn't have time to make this code pretty, no cleverness here.

Comment: no I meant the version with `stringstream`. I haven't yet re-run the benchmarks with your modifications, but I do see how it would be faster in parsing the strings.

Comment: I updated my test results. Your modified version is the fastest, congrats!

Comment: Nice new graphs.  The captions all say 2014b, but the headings in the answer say the i7 is 2014a?

Comment: @BenVoigt The heading is correct, the figure title is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution seems to work:

```
function array_of_numbers = char_and_sscanf_solution(list_of_words)

s = char(list_of_words);
s(s==95) = 32; %// 95 is '_'; 32 is ' '
s = [ s repmat(32, numel(list_of_words), 1) ];
array_of_numbers = reshape(sscanf(s.','%i '), [], numel(list_of_words)).'/1000;
```

Benchmarking results using `referee_timing.m` and `referee_test_case.m`:

```
Generating 10000-words test case...
Timing 10000-words test case...
  eval_and_loops_solution: 0.190642[s]
  single_sscanf_solution: 0.234413[s]
  approach1: 0.073901[s]
  char_and_sscanf_solution: 0.068311[s]

Generating 100000-words test case...
Timing 100000-words test case...
  eval_and_loops_solution: 1.957728[s]
  single_sscanf_solution: 2.426764[s]
  approach1: 0.766020[s]
  char_and_sscanf_solution: 0.706387[s]

Generating 1000000-words test case...
Timing 1000000-words test case...
  eval_and_loops_solution: 18.975746[s]
  char_and_sscanf_solution: 7.147229[s]
```

Computer information:

> Matlab R2010b 
>   Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bits Service Pack 1 
>   Pentium(R)Dual Core CPU T4300 2.10 GHz 
>   4 GB RAM

Comment: Hi, I added some code for generating test cases and timing based on `timeit`, and proposed a standard script for benchmarking. I'm looking forward to hearing your opinion (is it good? isn't?).

Comment: Very clean solution, BTW. +1

Comment: @CST-Link I think it's good... but it's becoming complicated :-) Anyway, I find it strange that some solutions take such a large time on my system

Comment: My idea was the following: instead of putting everything in the base workspace, each run takes place in its own function workspace, that is deleted at the end of the timing function. Plus, catching erros so they will not bother other timings is easy. Generating different cases, instead of using the same string all over again (which may be unrealistic), was a good idea of @Divakar. Sorry for changing the rules on the fly, I promise I'll be careful from now on.

Comment: @CST-Link You're right, it's a good improvement. However, my computer/Matlab version seems to be giving such strange timings that I don't it's worth it for me to update them. Maybe you could give them a try? Perhaps post an answer with timings for the proposed functions in your computer? If you do so, please include in my solution the optimization I mentioned in my first comment (use ASCII code for underscore)

Comment: The random lines of different length seems to be messing with your creation of `s`.  Since `char` pads unequal lines with spaces the concatenation of `_` is not right after the last number on most lines.  I'm not sure what a good work around would be, aside from my `sprintf` trick.  ;)

Comment: @LuisMendo I make a run right now, on my home PC. However, I got a strange error from calling your function: "Product of known dimensions, 100000, not divisible into total number of elements, 10." I'll look again, maybe I'm using an old version of your function.

Comment: @chappjc Damn. I'll see if I can fix it. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @CST-Link No, my function implicitly assumed equal-lenght words. See chappjc's comment above. I'll look into it

Comment: @CST-Link I have corrected my answer, and updated the timings according to `referee_test_case.m` and `referee_timing.m`.

Comment: @chappjc I solved it by replacing `_` with spaces. So multiple spaces are treated like one. Thanks again!

Comment: @LuisMendo Hi, I fell asleep yesterday night while waiting for my home PC to finish the tests. :-) Definitely I'll put my results tonight. Meanwhile, congrats on fixing the issue. :-)

Comment: Sorry my last comment was meant to end up at @chappjc's solution ;) But I like this solution too! +1 already for you.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! Same for you. And your approach seems to be the fastest!

Answer (score 3):

I'd apply [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) with a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) input to generate a single, fully-delimited 1D string (with delimiter at end of each line/string), and then use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to pull out the integers:

**extractIntsSprintfTextScan.m**

```
function M = extractIntsSprintfTextScan(list_of_words)

% optimized lines, see below for explanation of each op
M = textscan(sprintf('%s_',C{:}),'%.0f', 'Delimiter','_');
M = reshape(M{1}, [], numel(C)).';

% cell to string, adding _ suffix
% s = sprintf('%s_',list_of_words{:});

% extract integers given _ as delimiter
% C = textscan(s,'%u','Delimiter','_','CollectOutput',1); % can also use %d for signed
% C = textscan(s,'%.0f_','CollectOutput',1); % a little faster to put _ in the pattern

% matrix form
% M = reshape(C{1},[],numel(list_of_words)).'/1000; % remove transpose for faster output

end
```

**Benchmarks (previous timings now stale, see `sprintf`+`textscan` solution in [Amro's benchmark post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26552087/2778484) instead)**

**Machine**

> MATLAB R2014b 64-bit 
>   Windows 7 64-bit 
>   24 GB RAM 
>   Dual Xeon X5550 (2.67GHZ, 8 physical cores)

**UPDATE**: Change output type to double from an integer type. Re-run benchmarks.
**UPDATE 2**: Change format specifier from '%f' to '%.0f', maybe allowing it to speed up the scan since no decimals are requested.  Increase `N = 100e3;` (see the [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/a038a74945d84015e61b)).
**UPDATE 3**: New benchmarks with version 2 of CST-Link's timing functions (see *new* [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/702a645b12040acfce81) with suggested usage of referee_timing.m).
**UPDATE 4**:  Add Luis' solution.  Note that the results fluctuate since the data is randomly generated.
**UPDATE 5**: Optimization tweaks -- see Amro's benchmarking post.

Comment: +1 Wow, what a machine you have! Could you clarify which `N` did you use? Or even try different values of `N`? I got a strange variation with `N`. Finally, people might not know who "Jon" is :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo It's a fun little toy!  I just change the N from 6e4 to 1e5 (see the GitHub Gist for the actual script).  I have a feeling that since I have so much RAM and cores, that other benchmarks might not emphasize certain code aspects.

Comment: @chappjc Hi, I added new code for benchmarking. I hope that it will make the testing easier and more fair. Hope you won't mind sharing your opinion about it.

Comment: @CST-Link I've run with your new benchmark functions (very nice setup!) and put the [test script here](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/702a645b12040acfce81).  You should really put up the bounty using the formal bounty system, also 30 days is a bit long and I'm not just saying that because I like my results.  :)

Comment: My machine has problems with the large `N` for some of the solutions, so I can't compare. Would you mind adding my corrected solution to your tests?

Comment: @LuisMendo Of course not.  Good fix, Luis!  I'll update shortly.

Comment: @chappjc I will allocate the bounty as soon as the site lets me (need to wait for two days). As for the 30 days period: I think is just enough to get some solutions and also to test them against eachother. Also, note: your answer should be also divided by 1000.

Comment: @chappjc Pretty good answer and seems like sprintf is a nifty tool at least with the cell arrays! +1 on that. Also, I have added another approach and named it as approach4.m. Would you be kind enough to add that to benchmarks? I would do the same at my end too, but I am not sure how far I can go with my not-so-highend-system. Maybe we can start another community-wiki solution just for dumping the benchmark results?

Comment: @chappjc I added to the code a division by 1000, since the original scripts were doing this, hope you don't mind.

Comment: MathWorks really need to do something about the fact that `horzcat(C{:})` is significantly slower than `sprintf('_%s', C{:})`

Answer (score 2):

Challenge accepted! Here is my fastest implementation so far, and yes it's a C++ MEX-file :)

#### solution_mex.cpp

```cpp
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace {

// get i-th string from cell-array of strings
std::string getString(const mxArray *cellstr, mwIndex idx)
{
    mxArray *arr = mxGetCell(cellstr, idx);
    if (arr == NULL) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "null/uninitialized");
    if (!mxIsChar(arr)) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "not a string");
    char *cstr = mxArrayToString(arr);
    if (cstr == NULL) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "null");
    std::string str(cstr);
    mxFree(cstr);
    return str;
}

// count of numbers in char-delimited string
mwSize count_numbers(const std::string &s)
{
    return std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), '_') + 1;
}

// parse numbers
template <typename T>
void parseNumbers(const mxArray *cellstr, const mwSize len, std::vector<T> &v)
{
    // cell-array of strings
    std::vector<std::string> vs;
    vs.reserve(len);
    for (mwIndex idx=0; idx<len; ++idx) {
        vs.push_back(getString(cellstr, idx));
    }

    // join vector of strings into one
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::copy(vs.begin(), vs.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, "_"));

    // split string into numbers (separated by single-char delimiter)
    T num;
    while (ss >> num) {
        v.push_back(num);
        ss.ignore(1);
    }
}

};

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // validate inputs
    if (nrhs!=1 || nlhs>1) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "wrong num args");
    if (!mxIsCell(prhs[0])) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "not cell");

    // allocate output matrix
    mwSize len = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    mwSize sz = (len > 0) ? count_numbers(getString(prhs[0],0)) : 0;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(sz, len, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    if (plhs[0] == NULL) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "null");
    if (len == 0 || sz == 0) return;

    // parse cell array into numbers
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(len*sz);
    parseNumbers(prhs[0], len, v);
    if (v.size() != (len*sz)) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "wrong size");

    // copy numbers into output matrix
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), mxGetPr(plhs[0]));
}
```

The code is straightforward to read; I'm using the standard STL library where possible (no dirty tricks), plus there's plenty of checks and input validation, so it should robust as long you follow the input format described in the question.

I'll update with some benchmarks later, but for now you can test it on your own and compare against the other solutions...

Note the above MEX-function returns a matrix of size `n_numbers * n_words`, so you'll want to transpose the result.

Here is a wrapper M-function you can use to run under the referee program:

#### solution_mex.m

```
function array_of_numbers = mex_solution(list_of_words)
    array_of_numbers = solution_mex(list_of_words).';
end
```

---

## EDIT#1

Let's simplify the code a bit; this version uses much less memory by processing one string at a time, and placing the result directly into the output matrix:

#### solution_mex.cpp

```cpp
#include "mex.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace {
std::string getString(const mxArray *cellstr, const mwIndex idx)
{
    // get i-th string from cell-array of strings
    mxArray *arr = mxGetCell(cellstr, idx);
    if (!arr || !mxIsChar(arr)) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "not a string");
    char *cstr = mxArrayToString(arr);
    if (cstr == NULL) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "null");
    std::string str(cstr);
    mxFree(cstr);
    return str;
}

mwSize count_numbers(const std::string &s)
{
    // count of numbers in char-delimited string
    return std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), '_') + 1;
}
};

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // validate inputs
    if (nrhs!=1 || nlhs>1) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "wrong num args");
    if (!mxIsCell(prhs[0])) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "not a cell");

    // determine sizes
    const mxArray *cellstr = prhs[0];
    const mwSize n_words = mxGetNumberOfElements(cellstr);
    const mwSize n_nums = (n_words > 0) ?
        count_numbers(getString(cellstr,0)) : 0;

    // allocate output matrix
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n_nums, n_words, mxREAL);
    if (plhs[0] == NULL) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "null");
    if (n_words == 0 || n_nums == 0) return;
    double *out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    // extract numbers from strings
    for (mwIndex idx=0, i=0; idx<n_words; ++idx) {
        std::istringstream ss(getString(cellstr, idx));
        int num;
        while(ss >> num) {
            out[i++] = num;
            ss.ignore(1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## EDIT#2 (OpenMP)

Next step, let's make it multi-threaded; We can do this implicitly using OpenMP by just adding two lines of code! I am parallelizing over each string.

First we add the `omp parallel for` pragma, then we make the index variable `i` private to each thread, that way threads know the column starting index.

In the previous code from edit#1, just replace the last loop with:

```cpp
// extract numbers from strings
#pragma omp parallel for
for (mwIndex idx=0; idx<n_words; ++idx) {
    mwIndex i = idx*n_nums;  // starting index for i-th column
    std::istringstream ss(getString(cellstr, idx));
    int num;
    while(ss >> num) {
        out[i++] = num;
        ss.ignore(1);
    }
}
```

I'm running R2014a on Windows x64, and I tried compiling with both VS2013 and MinGW-w64 GCC 4.9.1. Let me point out that the GCC-compiled version is way faster than all solutions so far:

```
% compile with MinGW-w64
>> mex -largeArrayDims -f mingwopts.bat solution_mex.cpp -output solution_mex_gcc

% set appropriate number of threads
>> setenv('OMP_NUM_THREADS','4');

% quick benchmark
>> timeit(@() solution_mex_gcc(repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},1e6,1)).')
ans =
    0.6658
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you should provide a MATLAB wrapper that does the rest of the operations at least (transposition and division by 1000). Also, it wasn't exactly what I had in mind; that's why I specified "MATLAB-native." :-D But your answer IS welcome, nonetheless.

Comment: @CST-Link Well, this opens up a whole new set of solutions. I specifically stuck to builtin based in the instructions... Do you really want to start taking MEX solutions?  +1 For the great code, as always.

Comment: @Amro Well, I'm about to abandon MATLAB myself in the last solution that I'll propose: no function calls. Or maybe 4. :-) But no, for the sake of the fairness, I'd like to award the bounty bonus to an MATLAB standard-function-and-language code.

Comment: @chappjc, CST-Link: I posted a new multi-threaded version. Let me tell you, it is really fast!

Comment: @Amro Maybe you can check out my byte-twiddling solution too. Is pure MATLAB, and I'm curious how well it does on your machine.

Comment: @CST-Link: multithreaded MEX-function is clearly faster. For `C = repmat({'02_04_04_52_23_14_54_672_0'},1e6,1);`, `timeit(@() solution_mex_gcc(C).')` gives `0.6710` while `timeit(@() all_loops(C))` gives `2.0884`

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't dare to say that is not faster. However, is only 3 times faster. :-)

Comment: @CST-Link: I'm running on a core i7 laptop, but I'm certain the difference will be even greater if you run it on a beefy machine like that of chappjc. If you have enough RAM, increase the data size, you won't run out of memory. Also use more threads if you have the necessary CPU cores :) I have more benchmarks, I'll post them in a moment

Comment: @CST-Link Your byte-twidling solution (looping with `value = 10*value + (str(pos) - '0');`) is just how I'd craft a C solution if I had to avoid `atoi`, `strtol`, etc.. I like it.  By the way, I feel a CUDA solution coming on, but I might be the only one set up to compile it. @Amro I'll give it a run later, but it might be a good 8 hours before I get back to a computer.

Comment: @chappjc: take your time. It seems you have the highest spec machine of all of us, so you I'm deferring to you to run the tests if that's alright with you :) (I almost lost all my other work I have open after my laptop froze up from thrashing because I used too big a data size in testing!). I'm also thinking of writing a GPU/CUDA version, we'll see who comes up with one first :)

Comment: I modified your MEX function to use manual conversion instead of `istringsream`.  It's not a "safe" approach, but it gives about 4x speed up. @CST-Link This is along the lines of the byte-twiddling you are doing.

Comment: @CST-Link So, are we ditching the no MEX policy as proposed in the question? :)

Comment: @Divakar No. As far as I'm concerned we're just messing around for the hell of it.

Comment: @chappjc: nice. There's certainly room for tweaking the code, but personally I prefer to maintain code readability even at the cost of performance -- no "dirty hacks" and all :) If OP wants a pure MATLAB solution, I'd go for either your `textscan` solution, or the similar `sscanf` solution by LuisMendo, those perform well and yet are easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

**(Most recent Proposal)**

This kind of eliminates the last MATLAB-specific part of my anti-MATLAB solution; pure byte-scanning, loop-in-loop, mem-allocating stuff:

```
%'all_loops.m'
function array_of_numbers = all_loops(list_of_words)

        %'Precalculate important numbers'
        n_numbers = 1 + sum(list_of_words{1}=='_');
        n_words   = numel(list_of_words);

        %'Allocate memory'
        array_of_numbers = zeros(n_numbers, n_words);
        slice_of_numbers = zeros(n_numbers, 1);

        %'Loop trough chunks of cell array'
        for k = 1:n_words
                str     = list_of_words{k};
                pos_max = size(str, 2);
                value   = 0;
                index   = 1;

                for pos = 1:pos_max
                        if str(pos) == '_'
                                slice_of_numbers(index) = value;
                                value                   = 0;
                                index                   = index + 1;
                        else
                                value = 10*value + (str(pos) - '0');
                        end;
                        slice_of_numbers(index) = value; %'almost forgot'
                end;

                array_of_numbers(:, k) = slice_of_numbers;
        end;

         %'This is a waste of memory, but is kind of required'
        array_of_numbers = transpose(array_of_numbers / 1000);

end
```

**(Benchmarking)**
For the following configuration (obtained from [configinfo.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18510-matlab-performance-measurement))

```
MATLAB configuration information                    CPU: x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
This data was gathered on: 24-Oct-2014 14:19:31     The measured CPU speed is: 2600 MHz
MATLAB version: 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)                 Number of processors: 4
MATLAB root: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       RAM: 3289 MB
MATLAB accelerator enabled                          Swap space: 6576 MB
MATLAB JIT: enabled                                 Microsoft Windows 7
MATLAB assertions: disabled                         Number of cores: 2
MATLAB Desktop: enabled                             Number of threads: 2
```

the following results were obtained (3rd run):

```
Generating 10000-words test case...
Timing 1000000-words test case...
  approach4: Error - Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
  approach1: Error - Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
  single_sscanf_solution: Error - Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
  char_and_sscanf_solution: 5.076296[s]
  extractIntsSprintfTextScan: 4.328066[s]
  all_loops: 1.795730[s]
  eval_and_loops_solution: 10.027541[s]
Generating 100000-words test case...
Timing 100000-words test case...
  approach4: 0.252107[s]
  approach1: 0.370727[s]
  single_sscanf_solution: 1.364936[s]
  char_and_sscanf_solution: 0.515599[s]
  extractIntsSprintfTextScan: 0.444586[s]
  all_loops: 0.179575[s]
  eval_and_loops_solution: 1.010240[s]
Generating 10000-words test case...
Timing 10000-words test case...
  approach4: 0.026642[s]
  approach1: 0.039550[s]
  single_sscanf_solution: 0.136711[s]
  char_and_sscanf_solution: 0.049708[s]
  extractIntsSprintfTextScan: 0.042608[s]
  all_loops: 0.017636[s]
  eval_and_loops_solution: 0.099111[s]
```

You may notice a difference in the last step, between "Generating 10000..." and "Timing 1000000..."; in order to decimate the occupied memory (otherwise everything would fail on generating the test case) i used `repmat(referee_test_case(1e4), 100, 1)` instead of `referee_test_case(1e6)`.

Comment: Could you add benchmarks for `approach4.m` added in my solution? Sorry for the troubles! :)

Comment: @Divakar Timing on `approach4.m` is added. Would you post your own timing tests also? I'd be curious.

Comment: Well I had doubts over the present timeit based benchmarking, as it wasn't clearing out one approach's outputs before moving onto the next one. This was evident with the out-of-memory errors. So, I created a different benchmarking code, which alongwith the results based on my system config are uploaded here - http://pastebin.com/1EucNwYB What do you think?

Comment: @Divakar  Sorry, I'm at at work, pastebin is filtered. I'm not sure about clearing, because all the data is created in a function workspace. Once the function exits, all the contained variables are freed. Would you like to change the order of the scripts and put your functions first, and the memory intensive first? Like this it would be no issue with clearing (because there's no need, the me is pristine). Please let me know which order you'd prefer, and I'll accomodate.

Comment: @Divakar Also it would be nice to see how the codes are performing on your system. :-)

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, the https link gives me "page not available", changed to http but is filtered.

Comment: How about this one - http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1LMI Not giving up myself either ;)

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, but I guess our IT guys are good at filtering stuff. :-) When I'll get home, I'll take a look. But what is essentially different than what I wrote?

Comment: Can I edit the question with it so that you could have a look?

Comment: @Divakar By the way, we can lower the consumption of memory for the million test by using `repmat(referee_test_case(1e4), 100, 1)` and not `repmat(referee_test_case(1e5), 10, 1)`.

Comment: @Divakar Okay. Or post it as an answer - as you think it would be the best.

Comment: Well it's just a little benchmarking code, same as I had suggested yesterday but with three memory cases (low, medium and high memory stress cases). It's okay we can wait, till you get back home.

Comment: @Divakar Meanwhile, I think that you might be disgusted by my latest proposal - is almost no MATLAB in it. :-) I'm really curious how it performs on your machine/test.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, no MATLAB in what exactly? So, the links I have given you have the benchmarking code alongwith the benchmark results on my system.

Comment: @Divakar Oh, sorry, I tried again to be funny. :-) I meant that I also proposed another function in my answer, that eliminates completely the MATLAB-specific `eval`.

Comment: Ah I see now! Would be interesting to see it among the benchmarks!

Comment: @Divakar Just a couple suggestions for you and CST-Link:  [Gist.GitHub.com](https://gist.github.com/) is a really nice alternative to pasetbin.  Also, I don't expect everyone to have the latest version, but there were some [big speed ups in `textscan` in R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bugdhql-1).  (It's now about twice as fast as `sscanf` for no apparent reason). Although approach4.m and all_loops.m seem faster anyway.  BTW, it's amazing how far JIT compilation has come!  The completely naive, unvectorized, solution is fastest!  Cool.

Answer (score 2):

### Benchmarking

Few things must be noted on the benchmark codes used for this benchmarking. This is same as Amro's benchmark codes with these changes -

- The division by `1000` was added to all solutions to keep the consistency among solutions.
- The error checking for validity is removed. It won't affect the runtime results anyway.
- The datasize (number of rows) is extended to `1000000` and for that I had to keep the count of numbers in each cell as `8` to accommodate everything into memory. Also, I think this would present a fair comparison between vectorized and loopy solutions.
- The mex based solutions are avoided, but I would love to see runtime comparisons against those too, if someone would be too kind to include the solutions included in this
  benchmark with those mex based ones.
- For benchmarking GPU codes, [**`gputimeit`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/distcomp/gputimeit.html)
  was used, instead of `timeit`.

The codes are packaged and available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78tdwh0n7mksqw8/bench_cell_problem.zip?dl=0). In it, use `bench_script.m` as the main function.

**Benchmark Results**

[image]

[image]

```
           func               nrows    ncols      time  
__________________________    _____    _____    ________

'all_loops'                   10000    8        0.026996
'char_and_sscanf_solution'    10000    8        0.034492
'eval_and_loops_solution'     10000    8         0.22548
'extIntsSprintfTextScan'      10000    8        0.036889
'func_eval_cellfun'           10000    8         0.16483
'func_eval_loop'              10000    8          0.1845
'func_sscanf_cellfun'         10000    8         0.40217
'func_sscanf_loop'            10000    8         0.19508
'func_sscanf_sprintf'         10000    8        0.027505
'func_sscanf_strjoin'         10000    8         0.11128
'func_str2num_cellfun'        10000    8          0.4976
'func_str2num_loop'           10000    8          0.5303
'func_textscan_cellfun'       10000    8           0.547
'func_textscan_loop'          10000    8          0.3752
'func_textscan_sprintf'       10000    8        0.036699
'func_textscan_strjoin'       10000    8         0.12059
'single_sscanf_solution'      10000    8         0.17122
'soln_bytstrm_bsxfun_gpu'     10000    8        0.023365
'soln_sprintf_bsxfun_gpu'     10000    8        0.019986
'solution_bytstrm_bsxfun'     10000    8        0.031165
'solution_cumsum_bsxfun'      10000    8        0.047445
'solution_sprintf_bsxfun'     10000    8        0.028417
'all_loops'                   50000    8         0.13444
'char_and_sscanf_solution'    50000    8          0.1753
'eval_and_loops_solution'     50000    8          1.1242
'extIntsSprintfTextScan'      50000    8          0.1871
'func_eval_cellfun'           50000    8         0.82261
'func_eval_loop'              50000    8         0.91632
'func_sscanf_cellfun'         50000    8          2.0088
'func_sscanf_loop'            50000    8         0.97656
'func_sscanf_sprintf'         50000    8         0.13891
'func_sscanf_strjoin'         50000    8         0.56368
'func_str2num_cellfun'        50000    8          2.4786
'func_str2num_loop'           50000    8          2.6377
'func_textscan_cellfun'       50000    8          2.7452
'func_textscan_loop'          50000    8          1.8249
'func_textscan_sprintf'       50000    8         0.18556
'func_textscan_strjoin'       50000    8         0.60935
'single_sscanf_solution'      50000    8         0.90871
'soln_bytstrm_bsxfun_gpu'     50000    8         0.10591
'soln_sprintf_bsxfun_gpu'     50000    8        0.079611
'solution_bytstrm_bsxfun'     50000    8         0.18875
'solution_cumsum_bsxfun'      50000    8         0.27233
'solution_sprintf_bsxfun'     50000    8         0.16467
'all_loops'                   80000    8         0.21602
'char_and_sscanf_solution'    80000    8         0.27855
'eval_and_loops_solution'     80000    8          1.7997
'extIntsSprintfTextScan'      80000    8         0.29733
'func_eval_cellfun'           80000    8          1.3171
'func_eval_loop'              80000    8          1.4647
'func_sscanf_cellfun'         80000    8          3.2232
'func_sscanf_loop'            80000    8          1.5664
'func_sscanf_sprintf'         80000    8         0.22136
'func_sscanf_strjoin'         80000    8         0.89605
'func_str2num_cellfun'        80000    8          3.9688
'func_str2num_loop'           80000    8          4.2199
'func_textscan_cellfun'       80000    8          4.3841
'func_textscan_loop'          80000    8          2.9181
'func_textscan_sprintf'       80000    8         0.29494
'func_textscan_strjoin'       80000    8         0.97383
'single_sscanf_solution'      80000    8          1.4542
'soln_bytstrm_bsxfun_gpu'     80000    8         0.15528
'soln_sprintf_bsxfun_gpu'     80000    8         0.11911
'solution_bytstrm_bsxfun'     80000    8         0.28552
'solution_cumsum_bsxfun'      80000    8         0.43238
'solution_sprintf_bsxfun'     80000    8         0.24801
'all_loops'                   1e+05    8         0.26833
'char_and_sscanf_solution'    1e+05    8         0.34617
'eval_and_loops_solution'     1e+05    8          2.2465
'extIntsSprintfTextScan'      1e+05    8         0.37322
'func_eval_cellfun'           1e+05    8           1.641
'func_eval_loop'              1e+05    8          1.8339
'func_sscanf_cellfun'         1e+05    8           4.024
'func_sscanf_loop'            1e+05    8          1.9598
'func_sscanf_sprintf'         1e+05    8         0.27558
'func_sscanf_strjoin'         1e+05    8          1.1193
'func_str2num_cellfun'        1e+05    8          4.9592
'func_str2num_loop'           1e+05    8          5.2634
'func_textscan_cellfun'       1e+05    8          5.6636
'func_textscan_loop'          1e+05    8           3.981
'func_textscan_sprintf'       1e+05    8         0.36947
'func_textscan_strjoin'       1e+05    8           1.208
'single_sscanf_solution'      1e+05    8          1.8665
'soln_bytstrm_bsxfun_gpu'     1e+05    8         0.19389
'soln_sprintf_bsxfun_gpu'     1e+05    8         0.14588
'solution_bytstrm_bsxfun'     1e+05    8         0.35404
'solution_cumsum_bsxfun'      1e+05    8         0.54906
'solution_sprintf_bsxfun'     1e+05    8         0.30324
```

### System Config

```
MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit
RAM: 4GB
CPU Model: Intel® Pentium® Processor E5400 (2M Cache, 2.70 GHz)
GPU Model: GTX 750Ti 2GB
```

`configinfo.m` output (important ones only) -

```
MATLAB accelerator enabled
MATLAB JIT: enabled
MATLAB assertions: disabled
MATLAB Desktop: enabled
Java JVM: enabled
CPU: x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
Number of processors: 2
CPU speed is: 2700 MHz
RAM: 4046992 kB
Swap space: 9760764 kB
Number of cores: 2
Number of threads: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, in the MATLAB holiday spirit, is a highly-vectorized solution:

```
function M = func_voigt_loop(C)
    S = sprintf('_%s', C{:});
    digitpos = [find(S(2:end) == '_'), numel(S)];
    M = zeros(size(digitpos));
    place = 1;
    while 1
        digits = S(digitpos);
        mask = double(digits ~= '_');
        M = M + mask.*(digits - '0') * place;
        place = place * 10;
        digitpos = digitpos - mask;
        if ~any(mask); break; end
    end
    M = reshape(M, [], numel(C))';
end
```

It's only a few lines, easy to understand (grab the ones digit of every number, add in the tens digit, etc), and doesn't use any "exotic" functions like `eval` or `textscan`.  It's also pretty fast.

This is an idea similar to something I previously developed for doing `datenum` on an entire column of data in a CSV file, the MATLAB version, even with an particular pattern specified, was just horribly slow.  A later release of MATLAB improved datenum significantly, but my hand-tuned version still beats it handily.

Comment: Good solution. +1 Obviously, I like the `sprintf` bit and the *10 of each digit approach as that's how I did my MEX gag answer (poking fun at the idea of using MATLAB for top performance).  However, I'd argue that far from being exoctic, `textscan` is now the mainstream text processing function in MATLAB.  If you scan through the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) for the last few versions of MATLAB, it's clear that MathWorks has been focusing on building `textscan` into a very fast text scanner that is syntactically similar to `sscanf`.

Comment: that's pretty fast too. Here is what I get from a quick test on my machine (size = `1e4 x 10`): http://i.stack.imgur.com/1HD7H.png. As I've said before, results do vary between runs so always test it on your machine before making a decision!

Comment: @chappjc: I'm kinda-sorta using "exotic" to mean non-portable.  Everything in this answer can be easily replicated in some other language.

Comment: @Amro: You've got Parallel Computing Toolbox I presume?  I think we're seeing automatic parallelization, since it gained a relative order of magnitude moving from my system to yours.  Actually, maybe not that much.  But it did move past the three or four other fastest pure-MATLAB solutions pretty convincingly.

Comment: actually PCT toolbox does not do automatic parallelization, you have to write an explicit `parfor` or the like if you want that.. What you're seeing is probably the effect of JIT, which continues to improve in each MATLAB version. It is not really documented (I think that's intentional), but there are certain language constructs that if used will hinder JIT compilations. For example one should write "type-stable" functions where the variables do not change type in the middle of a loop or something. If you look at your code, `mask` was first defined as `double` but later changes to `logical`

Comment: @Amro: wrt JIT compilation, I've always assumed those optimizations are provided by Java.  But I guess newer MATLAB might generate different bytecode patterns that are easier for Java to JIT.  And I thought there was automatic parallelism (maybe SIMD rather than threading) for large matrix operations.

Comment: @Amro: Is there a function similar to `ones` that creates a logical matrix?  Or one should use `logical(ones(m,n))` ?  I really wanted a do-while loop, then the initial value of `mask` could go away entirely.

Comment: @Amro: Ok, redid it like a do-while, seems to have just a bit better performance.

Comment: @BenVoigt `true` will make an array of logicals

Comment: btw JIT compilation in MATLAB has nothing to do with Java. Like other interpreted languages, MATLAB first parses the M-code into an intermediate representation. It is this format that is later checked for possible [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), and if it can, MATLAB will just-in-time compile parts of it (expensive loops) to run at near-native speeds (it will need to be able to tell sizes and types of all variables involved, otherwise jit'ing is difficult)

Comment: @BenVoigt: you're of course right about SIMD-type of vectorization. This is provided implicitly for most matrix operations when the data is large enough to justify the overhead

Comment: @Amro It took forever, but I ran [updated benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26560439/2778484) including this solution with numbers of rows ranging from 100 to 1e6, on two different machines with R2014a (i7) and R2014b (old Xeon).  The machine and MATLAB version dictates the order, but there is a distinct group of 3 or 4 methods that are essentially the same.

Comment: @chappjc: thanks for taking the time for running all those tests. We certainly got many good implementations to choose from!